# I want to use the full range that the 64-bit integer can take. How can I do it in x86 Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I included the **stdint.h** in my solution and used **uint64_t**, but the result was not what i wanted. Here is the code that i used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./stdint.h"

void    main (void)
{

    //-- to get the maximum value that the 32-bit integer can take
    unsigned int test = 0 ;
    test-- ;

    //-- to see if the 64-bit integer can take the value that the 32-bit integer can't take
    uint64_t test2 = test ;
    test2++ ;

    printf("%u\n", test) ;

    printf("%u\n", test2) ;

    while(1) { }

}
```

And Here is the result.

```
4294967295
0
```

I want to use the full range that the 64-bit integer can take. How can i do it in x86 Visual Studio 2008? For your information, i'm using a 32-bit windows 7.

Comment: To print use : printf("%I64u\n",i);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%u` format specifier for `printf` is for unsigned integers. Use `%llu`.

Since this is C++ though, you might as well use the type-safe `std::cout` to avoid programmer error:

```
std::cout << test2;
```

Comment: Aha...! Thank you very very much!! I would keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

/* ... */

printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", test2);
```

to print an `uint64_t` value.

`u` conversion specifier is used to print an `unsigned int` value.

Note that the `PRIu64` macro is a C macro. In C++ the macro is not present and you may have to use `%llu` conversion specification.

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't ship with *inttypes.h*

Comment: @Praetorian but C++11 has *<cinttypes>* include which should define the *PRI* macros.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, but [VS2012 doesn't have that header either](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748766/). Also, interestingly, *§27.9.2/3* states in a note that macros defined in the header are available unconditionally.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've also tagged this as C++, I'll add the obvious way to avoid type mismatches like you've run into with `printf`: use an ostream instead:

```
std::cout << test2;
```

Comment: Which, of course, avoids the error when you change the type later.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That too. Well, if you change the type later, you might get an error, but at least it'll be a compiler error saying that type doesn't support insertion, rather than just invalid output.

Comment: Unless, of course, it's some poorly designed user defined type with an implicit conversion to `bool` (or something else for which `<<` is defined).  (I think it was Bjarne who once said that C++ makes it more difficult to shoot yourself in the foot, but when you do, you'll blow the whole leg off.)

Answer (score 0):

> In a book that i have, it says that program always convert any
>   variables to integer when it calculates. Is it possible to make the
>   default integer 64-bit?

This is 1) not correct, and 2) no, you can't tell (most) compilers what size `int` you want. You could of course use something like:

```
 typedef Int int64_t;
 typedef Uint uint64_t;
```

But you can't rename `int` to something other than what the compiler things it should be - which may be 16, 32, 64, 36, or 72 bits - or some other number >= 16.